# Filtering Options on PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe and I am trying to find the countries with the highest covid cases. I thought this would be an easy function but my code does not seem to work (Please see screenshot attached).How can I find the top 3 countries with the highest number of cases?[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ymJj.png)

Comment: you can post your data and code too for better understanding. Please take a look at this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
df_covid_3.orderBy(col("total_count").desc()).head(3)
```

hope it helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @sargupta Thank you! It worked but I was hoping to see the result in a tabular manner.